# MySQL trigger before insert - truncated incorrect DOUBLE error

Tags: mysql, triggers, truncated

I want to concatenate the new username with string and I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `rating_platform`.`admins_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `admins` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.username = NEW.username + "test";
END
```

I receive this error:

> ERROR 1292: 1292: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'test'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CONCAT` function:

```
SET NEW.username = CONCAT(NEW.username,"test");
```